# How to add css into xsl file?

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I have following xml file:

```
<GeneralAgenda xmlns="http://schemas.gov.sk/form/Notify.GeneralAgenda/1.1">
  <subject>Lorem Ipsum is simply dum</subject>
  <text>VLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</text>
</GeneralAgenda>
```

From this i have created following xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


<xsl:template match="GeneralAgenda">
  <html>
   <head>

    </head> 
  <body>

   <div id="main" class="layoutMain">
      <div class="layoutRow ui-tabs ui-widget-content">
         <div class="caption ui-widget-header">
            <div class="headercorrection">Lorem Lorem</div>
         </div>

         <div><label class="labelVis">Bla bla: </label>

           <span class="contentVis wordwrap">

             <xsl:value-of select="subject"/>

           </span>

        </div>

         <div class="clear"> </div>
         <div><label class="labelVis">Text: </label>
           <span class="contentVis wordwrap">

            <xsl:value-of select="text"/>

           </span>
         </div>
         <div class="clear"> </div>
      </div>
   </div>

  </body>

  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Im generating html file from xml, this works fine but i don't know how to include css styling into created xsl file. I need to add this css:

```
body { 
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Segoe UI', 'Trebuchet MS', 'Geneva CE', lucida, sans-serif;
    background : #ffffff !important ;
}
.ui-tabs {
    padding: .2em;
    position: relative;
    zoom: 1;
}                               
.clear { clear: both; height: 0;}
.layoutMain {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;   
}               
.layoutRow { margin-bottom: 5px; }              
.caption { /*width: 100%; border-bottom: solid 1px black;*/ }
.nocaption > .caption { border: 0px !important; }
.nocaption > .caption span {
    background: none !important;
    display: none;
} 
.caption .title { padding-left: 5px; }
.headercorrection { 
    margin: 0px;
    font-size : 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
}               
.labelVis {
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Segoe UI', 'Trebuchet MS', 'Geneva CE', lucida, sans-serif;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin: 0px 18px 0px 0px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    width: 190px;
    word-wrap: break-word;all: 
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
.contentVis {            
    float: left;    
    line-height: 25px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 0.75em;          
}
.wordwrap { 
    white-space: pre-wrap;      
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; 
    white-space: -pre-wrap;     
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   
    word-wrap: break-word;      
}   
.ui-widget-content {
    background : 50% 50% repeat-x #ffffff;
    border : #d4d4d4 solid 2px;
    color : #4f4e4e;
    border-radius : 3px;
}
.ui-widget-header {
    cursor : pointer;
    font-size : 0.8em;
    color : #494949;
    padding-left : 2px;
    border : #eae9e8 solid 1px;
    background-color : #eae9e8;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    border-radius : 3px;
}
```

I have tried to put it in head tags style but nothing happened, output was generated without styling, i also tried link tag but same result.

What is the possible solution for this?

Comment: You say your current XSLT works fine, but your XML has a default namespace `xmlns="http://schemas.gov.sk/form/Notify.GeneralAgenda/1.1"`, which you have not accounted for in your XSLT. This means the template match `<xsl:template match="GeneralAgenda">` is not actually going to match anything, and so you won't get any of the html inside the template being output.

Comment: so what should i put in <xsl:template match="GeneralAgenda">?

Comment: You need to declare the namespace in your XSLT as `xmlns:ga="http://schemas.gov.sk/form/Notify.GeneralAgenda/1.1"`. Then change the template match to `<xsl:template match="ga:GeneralAgenda">`. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kA. When you have done that, you can use Rupesh's answer to add in the CSS as you asked.

Comment: thank you this solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

Process 1 : Put your css in between head element as

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
   ....
 </style>
</head>
```

Process 2: save css file in your local and call it in between head element

```
<head>
  <link href="{CSSName}.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

Comment: @WaqasBukhary :), it is just typing, also html is not case-sensative

Comment: @TimC it is an editing error as edited by `WaqasBukhary`.